# linq union merging sublists

Tags: linq, unions

Given a list of objects as follows:

```
Instance
 - InstanceID

Version
 - VersionID
 - List<Instance> Instances

Activity
 - ActivityID 
 - List<Version> Versions
```

I want to produce a list like this:

```
Activity
 - ActivityID
 - List<Instance> Instances
```

currently stuck at:

```
(from activity in activities
 select new {
            activity.ActivityID,
            VersionGroup = (from version in activity.Versions
                            group version by version.ActivityID into versionGroup
                            select versionGroup)
            })
```

Just not sure how to get to the instance level.

```
(from activity in activities
 select new { activity.ActivityID,
              Instances = activity.ActivityVersions.SelectMany(v => v.ActivityInstances).AsEnumerable() });
```

Comment: You have to show what you've tried and we'll try to help you solve any issues you have. It's not *I need code, give me code!* site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `SelectMany` method to flatten a sublist:

```
var result = activities.Select(a => new
{
    a.ActivityId, 
    Instances = a.Versions.SelectMany(v => v.Instances)
                          .GroupBy(i => i.InstanceID)
                          .Select(grp => grp.First())
                          .ToList()
});
```

You can relpace the GroupBy logic with a `Distinct` with a custom `IEqualityComparer<Instance>`:

```
var result = activities.Select(a => new
{
    a.ActivityId, 
    Instances = a.Versions.SelectMany(v => v.Instances)
                          .Distinct(new InstanceComparer())
                          .ToList()
});

class InstanceComparer : IEqualityComparer<Instance>
{

    public bool Equals(Instance x, Instance y)
    {
        return x.InstanceID == y.InstanceID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Instance obj)
    {
        return obj.InstanceID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I haven't done the null check but they are trivial. This is, of course, assuming this is LINQ to Object as there is no tags that says otherwise.

Comment: thanks - just posted the got it.  I'll give you the credit on it :)